Execute bash script with right click + run as a program
I have a bash script in my_script.sh. The settings for it are these:

and in the terminal using ls -lh:
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 blah blah  44 Aug  1 10:51 my_script.sh

When I do right click → Run as a program, as shown below:

nothing happens. However, when I open a terminal and run ./my_script.sh, it works as expected.
What am I doing wrong in the graphical interface side?
In case it is relevant, this is the content of the script:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

firefox www.google.com

I am using "Files 46.2":


Can you mention the Ubuntu version that you are using??

You need a .desktop file to start your script with clicks. Your system has many .desktop files (Do: locate '*.desktop'). Use them as examples.

Thanks @waltinator, I managed to create a launcher for this in the global apps menu. Is it possible to have a .desktop file that can be double clicked to launch it, instead of in the apps menu?

AskUbuntu is a Q&A site, not a conversation site. If you have new information on your original question, [edit] the question and add it. If you have a new question, [ask] it. Do not try to start conversations in a Comment. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Nautilus has a script directory that you can install files to point at your scripts. When there is a file in the directory it will add an extra Scripts menu right click option.
${HOME}/.local/share/nautilus/scripts

(If you use Run as a Program menu option and point at this directory it will also run the scripts.)
A typical file would look like this: -
#!/bin/bash
sscript="/home/xxxxx/Documents/scripts/sh/ShowLeak/showleak.sh"
gnome-terminal -e $sscript

If you change line 3 to gnome-terminal -e $1 then when you run the script it will put up a terminal in edit mode. In this mode you can add the script path/file directly so you don't have to add anything to the file at all. There are also a number of other things you can change.
The following link give loads of other options which you might find interesting - including some scripts to try.
How can I make a script that opens terminal windows and executes commands in them?
